# Celery Groups: How to create a group of already running tasks?

Tags: python, asynchronous, celery, scheduling, group

I have a set of long running tasks I need to coordinate in group. The challenge is the tasks must be fired as soon as they can be created, not after all tasks are defined (as shown below).

The problem is `group(...)` does not accept `AsyncTask` and calling `apply_async` on the task results in every task running twice.

```
import time
from celery import group, chain, chord, subtask


# Run it
pipeline = rate_limited_task.s(end_task.s())
job_id_to_track = pipeline.apply_async()


# TASKS
@app.task(bind=true)
def rate_limited_task(self, downstream_task):
 
    tasks = []

    for random_number in np.random.randint(1, 10, 1000):
        # ... imagine it takes several seconds to generate a random number. This will loop many times
        
        task = parallel_tasks.si(random_number) # This needs to fire immediately 
        tasks.append(task)


    pipeline = group(tasks) | downstream_task

    return pipeline()

@app.task(bind=true)
def parallel_tasks(self, data):
    # Another long running task
    print(f'sleeping for {data} seconds')
    time.sleep(data)

    return data

@app.task(bind=true)
def end_task(self, results):

        print('End task')
        print(results)
```

Question: Is it possible to create a group of tasks that are already running (or in any state)?

---

Current solution (not ideal)

```
from celery.result import allow_join_result, GroupResult

@app.task(bind=true)
def rate_limited_task(self, downstream_task):
 
    tasks = []

    for random_number in np.random.randint(1, 10, 1000):
        # ... imagine it takes several seconds to generate a random number. This will loop many times
        
        task = parelel_tasks.apply_async([random_number])
        tasks.append(task)


    gid = uuid()

    result_set = GroupResult(id=gid, results=tasks)
    result_set.save(backend=self.backend)

    chain(
        group_tasks.s(gid),
        downstream_task
    )()
...

@app.task(bind=true)
def group_tasks(self, group_task_id):

    group_task = GroupResult.restore(group_task_id, app=app, backend=self.backend)

    # Less than ideal solution.
    # Needs logic to handle any failed tasks (solved in the group class)
    # Tasks should have an expiration time so that they are not retried forever

    if not group_task.ready():
        raise self.retry(countdown=1)

    with allow_join_result():
        results = group_task.join()
        return results
```

Comment: I think you cant. Somehow you have to loop the args for each task inside the group before they‘re executed. You could make your code faster by using a list comprehension instead of your for loop. Moreover I‘ve yet never saw the syntax of your pipieline line. Are you sure that you dont want to use chord(group(tasks))(downstream_task)? Or is this a shortcut which I‘ve not heard of yet?

Comment: pipeline is already a chord as Celery will automatically transform `group | task` into a chord, which is what is happening in `pipeline = group(tasks) | downstream_task`. I too believe dynamic adding of tasks to a group can't be done. In cases when developer needs something like this one way to solve it is to have every such task has a link (callback) that will be called once it is done, then you consolidate everything in that callback task. Yes, it will be called many times, that is the downside...

Comment: @DejanLekic I got pretty close but still haven't solved it yet. Here's what I think needs to happen. https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/_modules/celery/canvas.html#group

I think I need to implement my own `apply_async` and `_apply_tasks` function for the `group` class.  If I call `apply_async` on the tasks themselves, I'm able to create a `GroupResult` from that collection of tasks. The challenge is configuring another tasks to run when that GroupResult completes.
The ideal solution would be the ability to add tasks to a group via an `add` method and have those tasks get fired immediately

Comment: @mika The issue isn't about iterating through a list. Its that it may take ~10 minutes to iterate and in that time, 90% of downstream processing can be done. 

Firing a task immediately vs waiting for the full list of tasks will save A LOT of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot create a group of already existing tasks because Celery's groups are collections of lazy_evaluated signatures, not tasks. (The group actually executes the signatures, so the idea of "adding" tasks is a non-starter).

If you really want to do this, you can reach for celery's `vine.synchronization.barrier` implementation which supports adding tasks and waiting on everything being done before moving on. That being said, it is as you mentioned where you would have to implement almost all of `apply_async` and `__apply_async` from `celery.group` class to make it viable.

So, tl;dr, probably not worth it because...

---

You *can* pass in an generator into a group and it will start as soon as values are passed from the generator to the group.

Here is the PoC that shows that this works:

```py
from celery import Celery, group
import time, os, random
app = Celery(
    'tasks', 
    broker=os.environ.get("BROKER"),
    backend=os.environ.get('BACKEND'),
    enable_utc=True,
)

@app.task(bind=True)
def end_task(self, results):
    print(f'{self.request.id}: end task')
    print(results)
    return results

@app.task(bind=True)
def parallel_task(self,x):
    time.sleep(60/x)
    print(f'sleeping for {60/x}s')
    return x + 5

def slow_random(high):
    time.sleep(15)
    value = random.randint(1,high)
    return value

@app.task(bind=True)
def rate_limited_task(self, downstream_task):
    g = group(parallel_task.si(slow_random(10)) for _ in range(10))
    pipeline = g | downstream_task
    return pipeline.delay().id

pipeline = rate_limited_task.s(end_task.s())
job_id_to_track = pipeline.delay().get()
print(job_id_to_track)
```

Comment: I missed the window to award the bounty but I thank you for your answer! 